# Why does the Advanced IP Scanner return more IP addresses than arp command?

Tags: ip, lan, arp

I thought Advanced IP Scanner works like `arp` or some `ping` command in cmd.

When I use command `arp -a` in Command Prompt, it returns something like this:

```
Interface: 192.168.8.150 --- 0x4

Internet Address      Physical Address      Type
173.192.195.194       00-27-0c-bc-5c-c2     dynamic
192.168.0.106         00-27-0c-bc-5c-c2     dynamic
192.168.8.1           00-27-0c-bc-5c-c2     dynamic
192.168.8.11          c8-19-f7-9d-98-72     dynamic
192.168.8.27          d0-51-62-67-2c-af     dynamic
192.168.8.145         e0-63-e5-08-55-79     dynamic
192.168.11.255        ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff     static
224.0.0.2             01-00-5e-00-00-02     static
224.0.0.22            01-00-5e-00-00-16     static
224.0.0.252           01-00-5e-00-00-fc     static
224.0.1.60            01-00-5e-00-01-3c     static
239.255.255.250       01-00-5e-7f-ff-fa     static
255.255.255.255       ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff     static
```

I thought this command returns all visible IPs for my machine, but the Advanced IP Scanner returns this:

[image: Advanced IP Scanner result]

So as I can see the `arp -a` command returns only alive machines, but it doesn't return the unknown.
So, my questions are:

1. How does the Advanced IP Scanner work?
2. What is the difference between that program and the `arp -a` command?
3. What command in cmd should I use to show also the unknown devices and their IP addresses?

Answer (score 0):

The arp table entries have time to live..it means that it only show the most recently mac's with the host as communicated.

You can see in the arp -a result that in the column Type the address's are dynamic and static. The dynamic ones, after some time with no comunications with that host, are removed from the table. The static entries are permanent.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that was exactly the point of the asker: when the arp cache is emptied, with

```
> arp -a -d
```

, where does Advance IP scanner get its (dead) entries?